# How to automate password entry for Azure?

Tags: python, automation, subprocess, passwords

I want to automatically login an Azure system to access the virtual machine. I run the following code:

```py
process_1 = subprocess.call(key.SSH_KEY + ' | ' + key.PASSKEY, shell = True) # Login to virtual machine
```

and receive the following:

```
/bin/sh: key.PASSKEY: command not found
azureuser@xx.xx.1x.1xx's password:
```

It believes the `key.PASSKEY` is another command, when it is the input for the `azureuser@xx.xx.1x.1xx's password:` part. How do I make sure that the `key.PASSKEY` is entered as the password automatically when this subprocess command is run?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found using the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QfD8V_-7ok

I did:

```
    ch = pexpect.spawn(key.SSH_KEY)
    ch.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer
    ch.expect("azureuser@xx.xx.1x.1xx's password:")
    ch.sendline(key.PASSKEY)
    ch.expect("azureuser@vm")
    ch.sendline('ls')
```